# How to get PDF page location without creating new array

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

Is it possible just to find out locations of PDF pages in byte array?

At the moment I parse full PDF in order to find out page bytes:

```
  public static List<byte[]> splitPdf(byte[] pdfDocument) throws Exception {
        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfDocument);
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(inputStream);
        Splitter splitter = new Splitter();
        List<PDDocument> PDDocs = splitter.split(document);
        inputStream.close();
        List<byte[]> pages = PDDocs.stream()
                .map(PDFUtils::getResult).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private  static byte[] getResult(PDDocument pd) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    pd.save(byteArrayOutputStream);
    return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

My code works very well but

- I created additional  **List< byte[] >** to save page bytes. I would like just to have byte locations  - If I know  byte indexes of page **(page start location, page end location)** I'll extract this from main byte array.

**So might be I can find this information in PDF header or somewhere...**

Right now I'm trying to optimize memory, because I parse hundreds of documents in parallel. So I don't want to create duplicate arrays.

Comment: That doesn't look like iText code... are you sure that you are using the right tags for your question?

Comment: And to answer your question: a PDF file doesn't work like that. I want you to take the sum of the byte sizes in the List, and compare that sum to the original PDF. Then draw your own conclusions.

Comment: @Amedee you're right, it is a pdfbox question. Probably the [tag:itext] here means "if someone provides a solution using itext, that's fine, too" but that would make the question too broad.

Comment: @mkl then the OP should explicitly mention that. You are right. I'm flagging the question.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse 
wow. Size is a different in the list and in original PDF. So it means that each page has header and other in formations, right?...  So my approach is not correct... thank you..

Comment: It's even more complicated than that, but if that may be a theoretical abstraction that isn't very relevant for what you are trying to do. It also means that your original approach, even though very memory intensive, may still be OK. I don't know, I am not familiar with pdfbox.

Comment: @grep you probably should explain what you do with the split documents. That may make it easier for us to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I know byte indexes of page (page start location, page end location) I'll extract this from main byte array.

As @Amedee already hinted at in a comment, there is not simply a section of the pdf for each page respectively.

A pdf is constructed from multiple objects (content streams, font resources, image resources,...) and two pages may use the same objects (e.g. use the same fonts or images). Furthermore, a pdf may contain unused objects.

So already the sum of the sizes of your partial pdfs may be smaller than, greater than, or even equal to the size of the full pdf.